# How to fix routing failure with ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a small ASP.NET Core web app project named "OdeToFood". The dev environment includes:

1. IDE: Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 PC
2. ASP.NET Core 3.1
3. Use Dapper for data access from SQL DB
4. Not using MVC

In one of web pages, the jQuery .ajax will be used retrive a record from DB. I added an ApiController with type of "API controller with read/write actions" because the EF is not used in this project.

Here is the code auto generated by VS (no change was made).

```
namespace OdeToFood.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RestaurantsController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<RestaurantsController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<RestaurantsController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<RestaurantsController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<RestaurantsController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<RestaurantsController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to test it from the brower with following URLs:

1. https://localhost:44361/api/Restaurants
2. https://localhost:44361/api/Restaurants/8
3. https://localhost:44361/api/RestaurantsController
4. https://localhost:44361/api/RestaurantsController/8

They all failed with HTTP 404 error.

Since above code is already using the "Attribute Routing' with [Route ...], I think the first 2 URLs int test should work. But they didn't. I could not figure out why.  Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

In the startup.cs file, the configure section has following settings:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***`Your Scenario:`***

> Though the solution is very straight forward, I felt more explanation
> for you to get rid of any further confustions.

As you said `"Visual Studio 2019"` so if you have taken `asp.net core web api` project, it would be created with `weather forecast` `api controller` with default `startup.cs` like below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

So if you directly run the project it should run with the `default action` like below:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

> So now come to your projects `configuration` which is containing like
> below:
>
> ```
> app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
>     {
>         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
>     });
> ```
>
> Means its looking for `simple mvc razor page` and when you are trying
> to hit either of this `URLs` `1. https://localhost:44361/api/Restaurants or 2.https://localhost:44361/api/Restaurants/8` it should get `404` because it's not routed accordingly. So your `routing template` is not correct to `route api controller` directly. `endpoints.MapRazorPages()` is usually used for `Razor mvc page routing`.

***`Solution:`***

If you could add the `API controller` while you were taking your `RestaurantsController` I think it would be look like what you posted.
and request should route as expected if you replace the below `service`

```
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

> **`Note:`** You even can `override` your route template if you want. You could [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-up-conventional-route-1) also if you want which a
> [`conventional route`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-up-conventional-route-1).

***`Output:`***

[image]

What I tried show you is what mislead you and sharpen your idea. If you have any further query you have a look our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis-1). Hope it would help you accordingly.

Comment: Because the project uses both Razor pages and ApiController, I followed your solution to add endpoint.MapController and keep the endpoint.MapRazorPages setting. It worked for both.  If I have many places using the .ajax with jQuery, should I add a WebApi project to the solution?  Nowerdays, is  WebApi project replacing ApiController?

Comment: Thanks for the solution you provided.  I had a questions on whether to use ApiController or WebApi project in posted comments.  Could you give me some advice?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, well, if your `client side` project and `backend` project in different place it would be better to have `WebApi` it would be easy to maintain on the other hand, if your `client side` project and `backend` are in same project and they are tightly couple and in future there are less possibility to handle cross platform request then you can use `API controller` instead of having `WEB API` project itself. The important thing is `WEB API` specially designed for handling large data driven request, cross platform request where you would be dealing with `Json data` .

Comment: You can take `API Controller` on your `MVC` project to handle this kind of `data driven request` in that case you have to define your route. managing small kind of request adding `API Controller` on `MVC` project will also good. But if your project basically designed for dealing large scale data then `WEB API` would definitely be a good choice. Hope you got the proper explanations. Feel free to let me know if you have any further question.

Answer (score 1):

Try below in your startup.cs

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Comment below;

```
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```